# Xcode says: "No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc"

Tags: iphone, c, xcode

I am working on an opengl application and implementing a bezier surface in the iPhone and I am getting this:

> Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a
>   'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen
>   at this time.)
>       No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc

and sometimes I get malloc_error_break freed sum check error... so I put a break point there but it brings not useful info for me.

I could do some optimizations but I still don't know if current implementation really work.

I am testing my application in the simulator and with very small values (4x4 control points and 16*16 for my vertices grid) and still getting malloc error?.
I wonder how can I track or debug this? 
Most of the time I don't even get a error, the application just freezes (don't even crashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it was a simple bug. My simple factorial implementation was not handling negative values giving...  ;)